# A public reactive MockAPI like jsonplaceholder.typicode to return Flux

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor, jsonplaceholder

Is there a Mock public Api website that returns a reactive response. Like a Stream of Items instead of a List of items.  like we have `jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` which is non reactive version

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with using a Reactor `HttpClient` against that HTTP service: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty. I think it doesn't matter what server does since there is the same HTTP protocol in between.

Comment: It does matter, if you expect a flux of items and just get a list of items the conversion to Item from String will break, because the chunks will not be based upon items

Comment: @ArtemBilan if you run this code on this public api, and observer  what’s printed you’ll uderstand what I’m talking about 
`HttpClient.create().get().uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos").responseContent().asString().map(e -> {System.out.println(“chuck  - [[[ “+e+”]]]" ); return e; });`

Comment: I don't think the `Flux` server would help you somehow. See more about that `responseContent()`. It does return a `ByteBufFlux` of chunks based on some available bytes. You have to re-assemble items yourself. Something similar what WebFlux `WebClient` does with its `bodyToFlux()`. As I said before: on the HTTP network level it is just a sequence of bytes.